# Finding mixed transaction

Tags: blockchain, tumblebit

I have a hard time understanding how mixed transactions can be recongnized on the blockchain.

Is this type of transaction a mixed one ?

https://www.blockchain.com/fr/btc/tx/cf903272cac49e28ff0e5fa109758954ed403480f68224e8ca5ccce7fcabccaa

Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixing techniques are designed in a way so that it cannot be identified. There is no sure shot way of telling whether a transaction is mixed unless the mixing is shoddy. It might as well appear that this is a transaction where one party is using multiple inputs to pay multiple parties. Example would be an establishment accepting bitcoins for its services from its customers and pays employees/suppliers/partners at the end of the day using bitcoins. It would have to use multiple inputs and multiple outputs.

Having said that, there are some techniques for determining which outputs are created by which inputs and if it is mixing, but these techniques are not foolproof and often make assumptions that are not guaranteed.

Comment: *"Mixing techniques are designed in a way so that it cannot be identified"* this is not absolutely true, in fact many mixing transactions are quite obviously mixing transactions. The link between inputs and outputs is broken, but looking at the history of each output, it can be determined that it came from a mixing transaction. That said, some types of mixing (eg P2EP transactions) are in fact designed to be indistinguishable from 'normal transactions', but other other legitimate mixing techniques (eg Wasabi's mixing scheme) are not.